# Cron job of a shell script that needs user credentials hide credentails

Tags: cron

I have a a cron job on a python script that takes arguments credentials into a application...how do i mask the cerdentials when i cron the job so it does not appear in ps tables or  crontab output

Appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

To keep sensitive credentials out of the crontab and still supply them as command line arguments, you could replace `command` *credentials*

with

```
command `cat credentialfile`
```

This will also keep it out of your shell history files in the case of an interactive shell.

To keep it out of the ps tables would be more difficult. I'm not sure if you can do that if the credentials must be specified on the command line.

The command itself can also overwrite sensitive arguments to hide them from `ps`, but there is still a window of time where someone could see them. See this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88665/how-does-ps-know-to-hide-passwords